# Hiding Textbox in ReportHeader from another section in ActiveReports version 1.0

Tags: c#, activereports

I have a report that has ReportHeader, PageHeader, GroupHeader1, GroupHeader2, Detail, etc., and a SubReport in the Detail section and a SubReport in the ReportFooter.  I won't know if a textbox and line in the ReportHeader needs to be shown until after the Detail section has called the SubReport.

If the SubReport in the Detail section determines that it needs to display any data, it makes a change to a TextBox in the PageHeader on the parent report.  The SubReport in the ReportFooter is able to read that TextBox on the PageHeader to see if it also should display any data.

I need to hide a TextBox and a Line in the ReportHeader section after the Details are all rendered if the TextBox in PageHeader indicates that I should.  How can I do this?

This is the code I am trying.  I am displaying the colors only so I can see what is possible to change from that particular section I am trying.

```
string display = "Do not display Info";
try
{
    display = ((TextBox)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["TextBox80"]).Value.ToString().Trim();
}
catch { } 

if (display == "Display Info" )
{
    ((TextBox)rpt.Sections["ReportHeader"].Controls["TextBox20"]).Value = "";
    ((TextBox)rpt.Sections["ReportHeader"].Controls["TextBox20"]).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    rpt.Sections["Detail"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    rpt.Sections["GroupHeader2"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
    rpt.Sections["ReportFooter"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
}
else
{
    rpt.Sections["ReportFooter"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible the way you are doing it. By the time AR renders the detail, the reportheader has already rendered and cannot be modified, think of it like a piece of paper that has already been printed, we cannot back it out.

the proper way is to run the logic you are using in the subreport before the report is executed and use the information to properly set the visibility of the textbox in the reportheader.